# Round UIBarButtonItems in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make round (sort of notification counter which you see on most of the apps) UIBarButtonItem in Swift. I know how to do it but the thing is it is actually being round only when I am setting **the width as 34 and height as 24**. Are these magic numbers for UIBarButtonItems ? If I set the width or height (same , my desired frame is 30 x 30) for something else and calculate the **cornerRadius** based on the width then **it is not perfect circle rather rounded rectangle**. What is I am doing wrong ? My code is below :

```
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 24)
        button.backgroundColor = DarkModeUtil.isDarkMode() ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black
        button.setTitle("\(self.pickedAppActions.count > 9 ? "9+" : "\(self.pickedAppActions.count)")", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(DarkModeUtil.isDarkMode() ? .black : UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
        button.titleLabel?.fitSize()
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.width / 2
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(counterTapped(_:)), for: [.touchUpInside])

        let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "done")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked(_:)))
        doneItem.tintColor = DarkModeUtil.isDarkMode() ? .white : .black

        let counterButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        let buttons:[UIBarButtonItem] = [doneItem,counterButton]
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons
```

If I set same width and height for example 30 x 30 I get button like this:

[image: rounded rectangle rather than perfect circle]

Comment: I already tried that. My desired frame is 30 by 30 which is not working.

Comment: Width will be dynamic based on your counter number so it is obviously a rounded rectangle.

Comment: how can it be dynamic when I am specifying the frame ? I am adjusting the counter label by button.titleLabel?.fitSize()

Comment: Set CornerRadius with - height --> `button.bounds.size.height/2`

Comment: Dynamic in the sense it will increase width when you set 999 text in counter.

Comment: And yes as @Aditya said, set `CornerRadius` as per the `height`

Comment: Yeah but counter will never reach that. as you can see I am showing highest 9+ as counter label.

Comment: I m not sure but when a checked UIBarButtonItem height by default 34 so when you add the height of your button doesn't affect. so 34 by 34 work coz default height is 34.

Comment: yeah tried with setting cornerRadius by dividing height. But no use. same result

Comment: So there is no other way than using round background image ?

Comment: Can you show us some screenshot what are you getting on the UI?

Comment: sure I will update the question

Comment: One thing you can do is to add `UILabel` from the storyboard

Comment: @Aditya added screenshot in the question. Please check

Comment: @AnuranBarman Just keep the `height` and `weight` same like `40,40` and give it a try. And apply cornerRadius based on height.

Comment: @Niraj_iOS while 40 by 40 works but that does not look good UI wise. Button is way bigger than what looks good in normal navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

make height and width 34 work for me. here is a code. also no need to change `button.frame.size.width / 2`.

[image]

```
 let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
    button.backgroundColor = DarkModeUtil.isDarkMode() ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black
    button.setTitle("\(self.pickedAppActions.count > 9 ? "9+" : "\(self.pickedAppActions.count)")", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(DarkModeUtil.isDarkMode() ? .black : UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    button.titleLabel?.fitSize()
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.width / 2
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(counterTapped(_:)), for: [.touchUpInside])

    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "done")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonClicked(_:)))
    doneItem.tintColor = DarkModeUtil.isDarkMode() ? .white : .black

    let counterButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    let buttons:[UIBarButtonItem] = [doneItem,counterButton]
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons
```

Comment: you are using 34 24 in your code. That anyway works as I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can set corner radius of the Button using

```
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 84, height: 40)

    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.height / 2
```

**Note:** `Button Maximum height: 44 and Minimum height: 34` in UINavigationBar as checked from view hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code :

**For Round button you need to make height and width same value :**

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    button.setTitle("999", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
    button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.height/2
    button.clipsToBounds = true

    let counterButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    let buttons:[UIBarButtonItem] = [counterButton]
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons
```

Comment: while 40 by 40 works but that does not look good UI wise. Button is way bigger than what looks good in normal navigation bar.

Comment: @AnuranBarman you can set button font size and make width and height besed on font size.